# Image error when changing profile data

Tags: bug, profile-picture, gravatar, uploader

At the sign up process I only selected a gravatar for my profile picture and skipped the rest of the info inputs. After finishing signup I wanted to edit the rest of the profile information, but when I wanted to change them I only got this message: "Invalid Image Type"

When I click on change image and select the gravatar again it works!

[image]

Comment: Can you still reproduce it, or was it a one time glitch?

Comment: Thanks for the report! I haven't been able to reproduce this previously, but if this happens right after signup, that definitely gives me another thing to try.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I recently tried to reproduce this error again but now it works for me. But yesterday directly after the sign up process i got this error several times when i added changes to my profile. I'm not sure if it's fixed now or if the error only occurs after the sign up process.

Comment: @AdamLear maybe this information is also helpful for you, too?

Comment: Yeah, once you "fix" the image URL, this is no longer reproducible.

Comment: @Adam "previously"? Was this reported before?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, though don't ask me to find the posts right now. Drinking deep from the Documentation firehose here.

Comment: @Adam lol, you read my mind... I did search but found only non related reports. Good luck with Documentation, and kudos!